# How can I store the current value displayed on the screen?

Tags: javascript, dom

Building a calculator in JS and was wondering how I can store the current value displayed to the screen - (number in the orange box)

[image]

```
    for(let number of numbers){
        number.addEventListener('click', function(){
            let a = displayText.textContent += this.value;
            let b = a
            console.log(b);
        });

    }
}
```

Numbers - is a node list which contains this: `<button class='keypad numbers' id='nine' value='9'><p class='text'>9</p></button>` from 0-9. 
How can I store the current number in a variable and then use that value for whenever the user clicks an operator button: +, -, /, * 
From the example above, I tried storing the value of a into b then console.log(b) however don't seem to get anyway

Comment: You just need to put `a` outside of the for of loop.

Comment: ```let a = displayText.textContent += this.value``` or are you referring to b being assigned a copy of a?

Comment: Yes, just declare `a` in a place where it can be used, when you declare a variable inside `{}` it can only be used there. It's [out of scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) if you try to use it elsewhere.